# The most strange error in the world (PHP $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST and ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I hope you'll able to help me. I'm fed up of trying things without any solution and php it's just driving me crazy. I'm looking for help because I have a html document where I use ajax thanks to jquery api. Inside this file, in a js function I have:

`$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "c.php",
   data: "dia="+matriz[0]+"&mes="+matriz[1]+"&ano="+matriz[2]+"&diaa="+matriz2[0]+"&mess="+matriz2[1]+"&anoo="+matriz2[2]+"&modo=0&semana=0",
   success: Mundo,
   error: function(e){
     alert('Error: ' + e);
   }
 });`

This code allows me to send the information that I want to the file c.php where I have:

`include('funciones.php');
include('config.php');`

```
 $mierda = array();
 $mierda[0] = $_GET['modo']; 
 $mierda[1] = $_GET['dia']; 
 $mierda[2] = $_GET['mes']; 
 $mierda[3] = $_GET['ano']; 
 $mierda[4] = $_GET['diaa']; 
 $mierda[5] = $_GET['mess']; 
 $mierda[6] = $_GET['anoo']; 
 $mierda[7] = $_GET['semana'];
```

As you see it's very simple. My crazy problem is that with firebug I've seen that the data is sent well but for some reason I can't use it. I have tried with $_Get, $_post and $_request and always is the same problem. But this can be stranger... If I put:

```
echo json_encode($mierda);
```

then miraculously, the php returns the data that I have passed so in conclusion I have:

1. I can send the data to the php file well
2. I can print all the data that I have sent well just accessing yo $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST
3. I can't use any value separatly like $_GET['dia']

What's going wrong there?

PS. The include php files are functions that access to my database so there's no interaction with them.

Comment: Should use POST instead of GET, unless you want IE to cache the results.

Answer (score 5):

Your data is not URL-encoded. Try do something like this,

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", 
         url: "c.php", 
         data: {"dia":matriz[0], "mes":matriz[1] ....},    
         success: Mundo, 
         error: function(e){ alert('Error: ' + e); } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a json value use json to read that.

See
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/How-to-Use-JSON-with-jQuery-AJAX

Here is an example to read json value

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#submit).click(function(){
        $.post('your_php_page.php', {employee_id: '456'},
            function(data){
                console.log(data.first_name);
                console.log(data.last_name);
            }, 'json');
    })
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have a crazy problem. According to your question:

```
$mierda = array();
$mierda[0] = $_GET['dia']; //... and so on
echo json_encode($mierda);
```

works while:

```
echo $_GET['dia'];
```

doesnt. Try:

```
$mierda = array();
$mierda[0] = $_GET['dia'];
echo $mierda[0];

echo $_GET['dia'];
```

It will show you whether the problem is in the PHP, or the javascript.

Answer (score -1):

I have encoded the data as ZZColer said and the error is still.

Starx, it's not a question of the returning.

digitalFresh, in fact the error is from PHP because I can copy $_POST, $_GET array to a new array and print all this information but if I put after all things like:

If( mierda[0] == 0) {... The element is empty! and if I try directly $_GET['dia'] it says that this element doesn't exist in the array. Also I have tried $_GET[dia] or $_GET[0] without a solution.

**PD:**

**I don't know how but PROBLEM SOLUTIONED!**

**Thanks to all!**